# Combine for loops

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have two questions about my code. First I will show you the code:

```
partialname5 <- "EV"
EV <- ttest[grep(partialname5, rownames(ttest)),]
partialname1 <- "MYC"
MYC <- ttest[grep(partialname1, rownames(ttest)),]
MYCEV<-list() 
for (j in 1:ncol(MYC)) {
     t1<-t.test(MYC[,j], (EV[,j]))$p.value
     MYCEV[[j]]<- matrix(t1)
}

partialname2 <- "OBX"
OBX <- ttest[grep(partialname2, rownames(ttest)),]
OBXEV<-list() 
for (k in 1:ncol(OBX)) {
     t2<-t.test(OBX[,k], (EV[,k]))$p.value
     OBXEV[[k]]<- matrix(t2)
}

partialname3 <- "WDR"
WDR <- ttest[grep(partialname3, rownames(ttest)),]
WDREV<-list() 
for (l in 1:ncol(WDR)) {
     t3<-t.test(WDR[,l], (EV[,l]))$p.value
     WDREV[[l]]<- matrix(t3)
}

partialname4 <- "PIM"
PIM <- ttest[grep(partialname4, rownames(ttest)),]
PIMEV<-list() 
for (m in 1:ncol(PIM)) {
     t4<-t.test(PIM[,m], (EV[,m]))$p.value
     PIMEV[[m]]<- matrix(t4)
}
```

My first question is, is it possible to fill in my partialnames by this way:

```
partialnames<- c('EV','PIM','OBX','MYC','WDR')
```

And then by the first loop take the first argument.

the second question is it possible to combine this loops for all `partialnames`?

Thank you!

Samantha

Comment: You can do that with `sapply`. If you provide a minimal working example, we can show you how.

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example would help, but the short answer is yes. I think you're trying to t.ttest all combinations of values for identifying variables (rownames) of EV, PIM, OBX, MYC, and WDR, for each column. Is that right?

If so, this might work, but it's hard to tell without a reproducible example.

```
splits <- c('EV', 'PIM', 'OBX', 'MYC', 'WDR')
results <- list()
for(i in 1:length(splits) {
 for(j in 1:length(splits) {
   for(k in 1:ncol(ttest)) {
    results[i][j][k] <- t.test(ttest[rownames(ttest)==splits[i],k], ttest[rownames(ttest)==splits[j],k])
   }
 }
}
```